# AAD - how to change the email domain after creating a group

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory, subdomain

Using API Graph, I create an ADD group with an email address.
The domain for the address is automatically added to the one that is primary in the tenant.
I cannot change the default domain on the tenant, but I need to change the domain for the created group to a domain other than primary. How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Note that, you cannot update **mail-enabled** security groups via Microsoft Graph as they are **read-only** via API. Alternatively, you can make use of **Exchange Online** commands in PowerShell.

In my Azure AD tenant, I have couple of domains where one is **Primary** like this:

[image]

Now, I created one group named **`Sridemogroup`** that has Email with **primary domain** as below:

[image]

To change the **email domain** after creating a group, you can run below Exchange Online commands in PowerShell:

```
Connect-ExchangeOnline
Get-UnifiedGroup -Identity Sridemogroup
Set-UnifiedGroup -Identity "Sridemogroup" -EmailAddresses @{Add ="sridemogroup@smilingsri.com"}
Set-UnifiedGroup -Identity "Sridemogroup" -PrimarySmtpAddress sridemogroup@smilingsri.com
Get-UnifiedGroup -Identity Sridemogroup
```

**Response:**

[image]

When I checked the same in Portal, Email **domain** of group changed successfully as below:

[image]

Comment: Thank you, I managed to change it from the console after granting the Exchange Administrator role. But I need to use this script in the application, and MFA is required for the Exchange Administrator role. I was thinking about registering the application and logging in to PS using secret , but I don't really know what type of application permissions I need to give to be able to change the domain of the aad group email address. And is it feasible this way.